# Keeping the latest two version and delete the remaining

Tags: bash, filenames, ksh, rm

I have a list of files (say xsl format below) in one directory. I want to keep the last two version of all files. (I can delete the remaing files)

```
{A}_1.0.xsl
{A}_2.0.xsl
{A}_3.0.xsl
{A}_4.1.xsl
{A}_5.0.xsl
{A}_6.0.xsl
{B}_1.0.xsl
{B}_2.0.xsl
{B}_3.0.xsl
{B}_4.0.xsl
{C}_1.0.xsl
{C}_2.0.xsl
{C}_3.0.xsl
```

The remaining files present in the directory should be

```
{A}_5.0.xsl
{A}_6.0.xsl
{B}_3.0.xsl
{B}_4.0.xsl
{C}_2.0.xsl
{C}_3.0.xsl
```

How can it be achieved?

Comment: What does the `.1` mean in `{A}_4.1.xsl`? Why does your example keep `A_3` and `A_4`, instead of `A_5` and `A_6`? Similarly, shouldn't you keep `B_3` and `B_4`?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I updated it. Requirement is like that only. Is that be easily achievable using awk? 4.1 refers to version.

Comment: Do any of these versions go over 9? E.g `..._3.11` ?

Comment: Nope., but we might get the version like 10.0

Answer (score 5):

Assuming all the filenames in the current directory follow that pattern, with `GNU` ls:

```
ls -rv | awk -F_ '++n[$1]>2' | xargs rm
```

<sup>You can omit the `| xargs rm` if you want to check what it would remove first</sup>.

That assumes the part in `{...}` doesn't contain space, newline, single quote, double quote, backslash, tab or underscore characters.

The key is the `-v` option to the GNU implementation of `ls` that sorts by version number. If you don't have GNU `ls`, but have `zsh`, in `zsh` you can use:

```
print -rl -- *(nOn)
```

To achieve the same result.

Now, if the current directory can contain anything and you only want to process the files that are of the form `{x}_y.z.xsl` where `x` can be anything and `y` and `z` are positive decimal integer numbers, you'd have to write it (`zsh` syntax):

```
printf '%s\0' \{*\}_<->.<->.xsl(.nOn) | perl -0 -lne '
  unlink if /\{.*\}/s && ++$n{$&} > 2'
```

Or using `GNU` ls and `GNU` `bash` instead of `zsh`:

```
eval "files=($(ls -rv --quoting-style=shell-always))"
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | perl -0 -lne '
  unlink if /^\{(.*)\}_\d+\.\d+\.xsl\z/s && ++$n{$1} > 2'
```

Comment: whatever happened to parsing the output of ls...

Comment: If there were `somescript_1.awk`, `somescript_2.awk` and `somescript_3.awk`, in the same directory it would delete `somescript_1.awk`.

Comment: @hlovdal, yes, but they don't _follow that pattern_. I've added a bulletproof version in case the directory contains anything.

Comment: @Braiam, here using `ls` makes sense as we're using its version sorting feature. It's not a problem if the filenames are tamed. Using `xargs` actually brings more issues than parsing `ls`.

Comment: using variables with `awk` for number of files to keep:  `ls -rv | awk -v keepfiles=$keepfiles -F_ '++n[$1]>keepfiles'`

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in `ls *_*.?.xsl | sed -n 's/\(.*_\)[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\.xsl/\1/p' | uniq` ; \
do ls $i*.?.xsl | tac | sed 1,2d | xargs rm; done
```

This does the following

- Find the prefix for the different sets of files (e.g. `{A}`, `{B}` etc)
- For each prefix list all files and then delete the two last entries (done by reversing the list and deleting the two first entries)
- Execute `rm` for the files in the remaining list

This is based on the assumption that the alphabetical sort order is the same as the chronological order. Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, but the principle of deleting everything but the two last entries (for some kind of sort order) should be the same.

Comment: If there were `{C}_8.0.xsl {C}_9.0.xsl {C}_10.0.xsl`, it would delete `{C}_8.0.xsl {C}_10.0.xsl`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think the downvotes are undeserved. The answer might be incomplete but it is not incorrect! And I very clearly spell out the assumptions made. Or am I wrong? What are some good reasons for downvoting this answer?

Comment: I'd agree it doesn't deserve downvotes as it works on the sample provided on GNU systems at least. There are a few restrictions that you've not stated (like the `xsl` files must not be of type directory, their name must not start with `-` or contain blanks or quotes or wildcards..., cannot be `x_1.12.xsl`...). It can be simplified (like `-r` to `ls` instead of GNU `tac`, avoid `ls` which doesn't do anything here since the shell already lists the files. There would be problems with some non-ASCII charcters wrt sorting as well.